# Multiple image are automatically created?

Tags: assets

I am using Craft 4 and I noticed after uploading an asset, additional folders are created automatically with multiple sized versions of the same image I uploaded. This causes a lot of additional files taking up hard drive space.

Here are the list of folders created:

**"_34x9_crop_center-center_none"
"_68x18_crop_center-center_none"
"_120x33_crop_center-center_none"
"_240x66_crop_center-center_none"
"_350x96_crop_center-center_none"
"_700x192_crop_center-center_none"
"_1000x275_crop_center-center_none"**

Is this supposed to happen, and if so, what is the purpose and what can I do with it?

Comment: By the way, if anyone stumbles upon this question
In the ImageOptimize plugin, this causes a [problem](https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-imageoptimize/issues/356), as the plugin tries to transform SVG images for thumbnails in the CP

Answer (score 2):

Those folders are created automatically for new [image transforms](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/image-transforms.html). The folder name is derived from the transform size, focus point and cropping method.

Some, maybe all, of the transforms you're seeing are just created by the CP to display as thumbnails or previews of the image in different contexts. For example, the assets lists displays previews in one size, the preview of a linked asset in an asset field in another one.

Other transforms may be created by your frontend templates and/or modules on demand, see the documentation linked above for details.

> Is this supposed to happen, and if so, what is the purpose and what can I do with it?

You don't need to do anything with it. Transforms and their corresponding folders are created on demand and can be cleared out without problems. They will, however, be recreated the next time those image transforms are requested, so there isn't really a point to doing that.

You should *definitely* use transforms in your frontend templates to size images according to their function, output sizing and positioning. You never want to send original uploaded image files directly to the end-user, as they will likely be poorly compressed and way larger than they need to be.

> This causes a lot of additional files taking up hard drive space.

The generated images are mostly small thumbnails, so their file size will be negligible. Furthermore, storage is cheap. If your hosting has a super lower hard drive space limit to the point where this is actually a problem, find a different hosting provider.